# onCreate() isn't being called

Tags: android, android-activity, manifest, breakpoints

I just got a very strange problem which I have now spendt hours trying to solve. When I try to run my android app (both on my phone and in the emulator) I get nothing. The activity label from the AndroidManifest file (android:label="@string/list_name") is set correctly, but otherwise I just have a blink screen.

I inserted a breakpoint together with 30 Log.d()'s right after the super() in my onCreate() method, but the breakpoint is never reached, and the Log.d()'s are never printed. Also, I do not get any exceptions in logcat.

The app worked before, and I have no idea how the it can be that the breakpoint never is reached.

PS: It is my main activity

PS2: I've cleaned the project, rebuilt it, rebooted. The problem didn't disappear :(

PS3: My onCreate() is quite long, but this is how it starts:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.episode);
        Log.d("Very Strange", "This is never printed");
        Log.d("Very Strange", "This is never printed");
        // no breakpoints is every reached
```

My manifest file can be found here: http://pastebin.com/UcKbYeGC

Comment: can you post your manifest and your main activity?

Comment: Also your `episode.xml` would be a good thing to see, since your `onCreate` looks quite normal. Are you extending the regular `Activity` or something custom?

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
 {
    Log.d("Very Strange", "Printed #1?");
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    Log.d("Very Strange", "Printed #2?");
    setContentView(R.layout.episode);
    Log.d("Very Strange", "This is never printed");
    Log.d("Very Strange", "This is never printed");
```

*Just an offtopic tip*: use a control version system to ensure you can rollback or compare the working one with the current

Answer (score 1):

The call of `super()` is not correct, as it just calls the empty constructor of the Activity class. You need to call the static method `super.onCreate()` in order to generate the Activity correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Your activity myListView is the activity that's started on application start. Is this correct? Else, have a look at your manifest and specify the correct intent filter for your episodes activity (simply cut/paste it from the MyListView entry in your manifest)